Error loading sempy library on python version 3.11.9
I'm working on VS Code with Python 3.11.9 trying to load the library sempy.
When running the import:
import sempy.fabric as fabric

I get the error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 3
      1 #Conexión a modelo semántico de PBI 
      2 import sempy  
----> 3 import sempy.fabric as fabric

File c:\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sempy\fabric\__init__.py:3
      1 from .._utils._telemetry import log_telemetry
----> 3 from sempy.fabric._flat import (
      4     create_lakehouse,
      5     create_tom_server,
      6     create_trace_connection,
      7     create_notebook,
      8     create_workspace,
      9     delete_item,
     10     evaluate_dax,
     11     evaluate_measure,
     12     execute_xmla,
     13     execute_tmsl,
     14     get_roles,
     15     get_row_level_security_permissions,
     16     get_refresh_execution_details,
     17     get_tmsl,
     18     list_items,
...
---> 46     arg_str = _construction_repr(dtype, include_align=False)
     47     if dtype.isalignedstruct:
     48         arg_str = arg_str + ", align=True"

And I have no idea what can be causing this.

Could you please update your post and share your code snippet ? It's hard to tell what is the cause from just this log.

Can this answer solve your problem?
